# quotients of triangle groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

The $(p,q,r)$ triangle group is the group with presentation $[a,b | a^p=b^q=(ab)^r=1]$.  Has anyone classified the (infinite) quotients of the $(2,4,4)$ triangle group?

Comment: The triangle group in question has a normal subgroup of index 8 isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.  Therefore, any quotient has a normal subgroup of index at most 8 that's a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.  How much more information do you need?

Comment: So, in other words, **yes**.

Comment: That subgroup of index 8 is the commutator, so every quotient has a commutator which is (i) of index at most 8 and (ii) a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.